# How to set Height of p-table to window height

Tags: css, angular, primeng, p-table

**Problem:**
I'm trying to set the height of a prime p-table in angular. I already searched the net and found so many results but none worked so far (probably due to this problem beeing around for many years and changes to the framework disabled certain solutions).

I already tried two approaches the first is in the code below. The second is setting the height of the parent div of the p-table to innerWindowHeight and setting scrollheight of p-table to flex (doesn't work either).

**Tools:** Angular 14.2.0 and PrimeNG 14.1.1 in a fresh project

I have the following html code in **app.component.html**:

```
<div>
 <p-table #table
       (window:resize)="onResize()"
       [value]="data"
       [paginator]="true"
       [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
       [scrollable]="true"
       [scrollHeight]="tableScrollHeight"
       [rows]="10"
       [rowsPerPageOptions]="rowsPerPage"
       styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines p-datatable-striped p-datatable-sm"
       currentPageReportTemplate="{first} to {last} of {totalRecords} records">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
   <tr>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Description</th>
     <th>Value</th>
     <th>Tax</th>
   </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-entry>
   <tr>
     <td>{{entry.date}}</td>
     <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
     <td>{{entry.description}}</td>
     <td>{{entry.value}}</td>
     <td>{{entry.tax}}</td>
   </tr>
  </ng-template>
 </p-table>
</div>
```

And the following **app.component.ts** :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Testapp';
  data: any[];
  tableScrollHeight: string = "700px";
  rowsPerPage: number[] = [5, 10, 20, 50];

  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
    let entry: any = {};
    entry.description = "First entry";
    this.data.push(entry);
  }

  onResize() {
    this.tableScrollHeight = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

**Behaviour I want to implement:**
What I want is, that the Paginator stays at the bottom of the window even if the table is empty or dosen't have enough entries to fill the window and that the table is scrollable (header staying at top) as soon as the table rows are bigger than the screen size.

To clarify what I want to acomplish here a screenshot how it looks:
[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0pWP.png)

And here a screenshot how I want it to look:
[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxV31.png)

**Question:**
Is it possible to acomplish this in a clean way?

Like suggested in the comment I added a **stackblitz** : https://angular-ivy-sfk7pw.stackblitz.io

**Edit:**
I found that if you set scrollHeight of table a **div** inside the table (generated from primeng) with class **p-datatable-wrapper** gets the style "**max-height**: **XXX**px" where as **XXX** is the **value from tableScrollHeight**. I could probably write a CSS selector to change the style to min-width but that's probably not a good Idea since I would have to access the dom from the typscript file and search for the auto generated div.

Comment: For better you can provide a stackblitz

Comment: I added a stackblitz though I had to use an older version of PrimeNG since the 14.1.X won't run on stackblitz without errors. So I used 14.0.1

Comment: Why you don't try to create your own table component? I mean, it's better than use table library.

Comment: I use primefaces components for everything in angular and I like the features of the table too. The only down side, for me at last, is that you can't set a height here.

Comment: If you like to see how to build advance table, maybe you can try to see it at here: https://github.com/ngid-dev/ngid-table/tree/development. "If you like". So you can build your own, and customize it like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add this style to your `css/scss`, but this is not a best practice.

```
.p-datatable-wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}
```

**Note:** `100vh` is your screen height and `90px` it's an example your pagination height.

That's it. I hope it can help.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and put it in the app.component.css file but it doesn't even show up in the dom if I inspect the table with dev tools.

Comment: Try to add in global or root style, or if you're use app.component.css or spesific-component.css, then you should have to use `ViewEncaptulations`

Comment: Ah I had to set ViewEncaptulations to ViewEncapsulation.None now it works. I would love to see if someone knows a solution with the `scrollHeight="flex"` which also didn't work and would probably the best practice as it would use what the framework provides. Thanks for your help much appreciated <3

Comment: Use `dvh` instead of `vh`, because mobile/tablet users might get a scrollbar otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Though not the best of practices, taking from [Titus'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73799214/15403057) response, you could add it to the component's SCSS as:

```
::ng-deep .p-datatable-wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 90px) !important;
}
```

With this, you wouldn't need to set `ViewEncapsulation.None`.